# I want to insert numbers by using single Pushbuttons on two different QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qlineedit

I have designed UI of Forgot password in which I have taken Pushbuttons and two QLineEdits(old password & new password). I am able to insert numbers in old password but later, I want to insert in new password using same push button how is it possible? can anyone tell me? I converted my .ui file to .py file using pyuic5 -x ___.ui -o ___.py command and further edited my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Window14.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Window_14(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window_14):
        Window_14.setObjectName("Window_14")
        Window_14.resize(800, 480)
        Window_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Window_14)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 291, 441))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 26);\n"
"border-radius: 50px;")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Window_14)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 26);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Window_14)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 26);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 230, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 230, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Window_14)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 10, 60, 60))
        self.toolButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.toolButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/Home.PNG"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.toolButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
        self.toolButton.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Window_14)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 30, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(23)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(200, 200, 26);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 350, 130, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(47)
        self.pushButton_13.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_13.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/Ok.PNG"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_13.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_13.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(130, 60))
        self.pushButton_13.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.pushButton_13.setFlat(True)
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Window_14)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 80, 150, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Window_14)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 150, 30))
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 350, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 350, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 410, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_10.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_10.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 350, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 290, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 290, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 290, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 230, 40, 40))
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("   border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Window_14)
        self.toolButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 10, 51, 51))
        self.toolButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.toolButton_2.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Images/Back.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.toolButton_2.setIcon(icon2)
        self.toolButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
        self.toolButton_2.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 410, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Window_14)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 410, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")

        self.retranslateUi(Window_14)
        #self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit_2.setFocus)
        #self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit_2.setFocus)
        #self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit_2.show)
        #self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit_2.update)
        #QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Window_14)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_8)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_9)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_10)
        self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_11)
        #self.pushButton_12.clicked.connect(self.PushButton_12)

       
        
    def PushButton_11(self):
        self.lineEdit.backspace()

    def PushButton_12(self):
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed()
    
    def PushButton_1(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("1")
 
    def PushButton_2(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("2")
    def PushButton_3(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("3")
    def PushButton_4(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("4")
    def PushButton_5(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("5")
    def PushButton_6(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("6")
    def PushButton_7(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("7")
    def PushButton_8(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("8")
    def PushButton_9(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("9")
    def PushButton_10(self):
        self.lineEdit.insert("0")

    def retranslateUi(self, Window_14):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Window_14.setWindowTitle(_translate("Window_14", "Form"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Window_14", "Enter the Old Password"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Window_14", "Enter the New Password"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Window_14", "1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Window_14", "2"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Window_14", "Restart"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Window_14", "Enter Old Password"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Window_14", "Enter New Password"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Window_14", "9"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Window_14", "7"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("Window_14", "0"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Window_14", "8"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Window_14", "6"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Window_14", "5"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Window_14", "4"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Window_14", "3"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("Window_14", "<"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("Window_14", "Enter"))
import Image_Resource


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window_14 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Window_14()
    ui.setupUi(Window_14)
    Window_14.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use `QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget()` instead of `self.lineEdit`, such as `def PushButton_1(self): QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget().insert("1")`

Comment: @eyllanesc I have replaced def PushButton_1(self): self.lineEdit.insert("1") by def PushButton_1(self): QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget().insert("1") but still it show error that "python has stopped working" when I press the push buttons.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have replaced def PushButton_1(self): self.lineEdit.insert("1") by def PushButton_1(self): QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget().insert("1") but still it show error that "python has stopped working" when I press the push buttons.